# Trouble understanding the answer to combinations question

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I attempted the following question

```
How many ways can a team of 24 hockey players choose a captain and two
alternate captains?
```

The correct answer in the end turned out to be `6072`, computed by multiplying 24 by the result of the combination $C(23, 2) = 253$:

24 * $ \dfrac{23!}{2!(23-2)!} $

I do not understand why this is the case however. Why make the distinction between the 24 and then the combination of $C(23, 2)$? My initial attempt involved simply using the combination formula with with `24` as the total and `3` as the sample, that being the captain and 2 alternate captains in the problem. This would have given me:

$ \dfrac{24!}{3!(24-3)!} = 2024 $

I am struggling to figure out what I am overlooking in this problem.

Comment: Which of your three selections is the Captain?  Note that your answer is off by a factor of $3$ (each of your choices gives us $3$ choices for Captain).

Comment: Captain $\neq$ Alternate captains

Comment: alternative captains are interchangeable, but not the captain who needs to be tagged.  So you choose 1 Captain and 2 (unordered) alternatives.

Comment: You could choose the three special people ${24 \choose 3}$ ways and then choose the captain from those ${3 \choose 1}$ ways, with ${24 \choose 3} \times{3 \choose 1} =6072$ .  Note that it is true in general that ${n \choose k}\times{k \choose 1} = n\times {n-1 \choose k-1} = \frac{n!}{1!(k-1)!(n-k)!}$ and there are may approaches which give the same answer

Comment: "Why make the distinction between the 24 and then the combination of C(23,2)?" Because you have to pick one person out of the 24 to be the captain. You are picking 3 people but aren't doing anything about determining which of those three will be the captain and which to will be the alternate captains.....or think of it this way. You pick three people; it so happens you pick Bob, Ann, and Fred. That is one of 2024 ways to pick them.  But now you must select one of those three to be the captain.  There are three choices for that. There are $3\times 2024$ ways to pick a captain and two others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having chosen $3$ special players from the $24$ players (via one of $\displaystyle\binom{24}3$ possible ways),

you next need to elect one of the three to be the actual captain (via one of $3$ possible ways).